# matplotlib figure freezes

Tags: windows-7, matplotlib

My problem is that after the figure is drawed the window of the figure freezes and I can't zoom, nor use that window anymore. I have to close it. Here's my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
abra = plt.figure()
tengely = abra.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
x = np.linspace(0, 20, 100)
y = np.sin(x)
y2 = np.cos(x)
tengely.plot(x, y)
tengely.plot(x, y2, 'g')
plt.legend(('szinusz', 'koszinusz'), 'upper right')
tengely.set_xlabel('$x$')
tengely.set_ylabel('$\sin(x)$ és $\cos(x)$')
tengely.set_title('$\sin(x)$ és $\cos(x)$')
abra.show()
```

What can be the problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Freezes are often dependent on the exact installation: Windows/Mac, OS version, Python 2.7 or 3.x, Matplotlib 1.x etc. It helps if you provide that information.
I notice two things about your code: 
1. When you use LaTeX labels you should prepend the string with an `r` for a raw string: `set_title(r"\sin(x)")`. 
2. In the `ylabel` and `title` you use an 'é' which may or may not give problems with encoding. 
My advice: try to minimize the code. Does it still freeze when you only plot the the sine? Then add more code line by line and see where the problem starts.

Comment: Windows 7, Python 3.2, matplotlib 1.2.0 and numpy 1.4. I've corrected the raw string problem, and tried with only the sine, and it still crashes... Any other idea?

Comment: are you running this interactively or from a script?

Comment: I've tried it running interactively in idle and also in ipython3, but it still freezes.